# How to get video link after uploading video to Youtube with Youtube API v3?

Tags: ios, objective-c, hyperlink, youtube, youtube-api

I am able to upload videos with the way described in 
[Introduction#Uploading_Files](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/wiki/Introduction#Uploading_Files), but how do I get a link to that uploaded video so that I can send that link to user to view ?
I found an article says you can use

```
[[[video mediaGroup] mediaContents] objectAtIndex:0] URLString]
```

to get the link in `GData`, but not found any article says how to do it with Youtube API v3.
Does anyone have good suggestion ?

Answer (score 3):

It seems there is no property to get a link of uploaded video. But there is a video id returned, I compose video URL by myself:

```
GTLServiceTicket *ticket = [service executeQuery:query
                               completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, id object, NSError *error) {
    GTLYouTubeVideo *video = (GTLYouTubeVideo *)object;
    NSString *videoURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%@", video.identifier];
}];
```